# Let golang close used channel after all goroutines finished

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to run a number of goroutines which will give their results to a channel. I need a good way to let channel close after all goroutines are done.

My first try is to close it after spawn all go routines but I think somehow the channel is closed before all goroutines can send their results.

```
for i:=0; i<=10;i++{
  go func(){
    result:=calculate()
    c<-result
  }()
}
close(c)
for result:= range c{
  all_result=append(all_result, result...)
}
```

Then, my second try I come up with counting a thread and close it after no thread is running.

```
for i:=0; i<=10;i++{
  go func(){
    atomic.AddUint64(&go_routine_count, 1)
    result:=calculate()
    c<-result
    atomic.AddUint64(&rt_count, ^uint64(0))
  }()
}
go func(){
  for{
    // some little time to let above goroutine count up go_routine_count before this goroutine can actually check go_routine_count==0
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    go_current_routine_count:=atomic.LoadUint64(&go_routine_count)
    if go_routine_count==0{
      close(c)
    }
  }
}()
for result:= range c{
  all_result=append(all_result, result...)
}
```

It works but I feel there might be more correct or more efficient way. Also, somehow in some case if the later goroutine for count check is run before the goroutines in loop, this method won't work.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) type should encapsulate what you want to do, without needing sleep calls or busy waiting. It allows you to wait on an arbitrary number of tasks, not worrying about in which order they complete.

Taking your original example, you could alter it to use a wait group like so:

```
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(){
            result := calculate()
            c <- result
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    // Close the channel when all goroutines are finished
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()

    for result := range c {
        all_result = append(all_result, result...)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for nice solution. I was wondering if I use this, do I actually need the latter goroutine for closing channel.
So, I tried just `wg.Wait(); close(c)` without goroutine and it gave me an deadlock error. Why is that?

Comment: Your goroutines will be blocked trying to write to the channel `c` until values start to be read in the final for loop.  The `wg.Wait()` call will also be blocked, since it is waiting on the `wg.Done()` calls.  So you really do need the extra goroutine in this case.

Comment: [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721283/james-henstridge) is right, the right way is to use a goroutine.
also if you would use a buffered channel like `c := make(chan any, 10)` then you wouldn't get this error the channel would hold the data till it gets closed and drained