# How to wait for goroutines to finish and read the channel without a lock?

Tags: go, goroutine

I went through a number of examples and questions here on SO, but still can't get a rather simple code working as expected:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go readFile("A", ch, wg)
    go readFile("B", ch, wg)
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()
    printer(ch)
}

func readFile(name string, ch chan string, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    file, err := os.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("was not able to read from file %s: %s", name, err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        ch <- scanner.Text()
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func printer(ch chan string) {
    for val := range ch {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

So I'm reading from two files, pushing read lines into a channel and then simply print them out (some code was simplified from unneeded detailes)

Two goroutines, WaitGroup for both of them, reparate goroutine with Wait and close channel.

From mine point of view this is pretty much identical to this question and the exepted answer: [Let golang close used channel after all goroutines finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819622/let-golang-close-used-channel-after-all-goroutines-finished#21819794)

So what's wrong in my case?

Comment: Try passing a WaitGroup pointer to `readFile` instead of a value.

Comment: "A WaitGroup must not be copied after first use." Use a pointer to a WaitGroup instead.

Comment: Running `go vet`, or having even a single unit test will show the error immediately.

Comment: Getting or not getting them problem wasn't the issue though. The issue was me not seeing that I'm passing a value instead of a pointer.

Comment: Yes, `go vet` warns you that you’re copying the value, and `go test` runs `go vet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by following the documentation for the `sync.WaitGroup` instructions:

> [Package sync](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/)
>
> ```
> import "sync"
> ```
>
> [type WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)
>
> A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish. The main
>   goroutine calls Add to set the number of goroutines to wait for. Then
>   each of the goroutines runs and calls Done when finished. At the same
>   time, Wait can be used to block until all goroutines have finished.
>
> A WaitGroup must not be copied after first use.

---

> **A WaitGroup must not be copied after first use.**

Comment: >A WaitGroup must not be copied after first use. - They should put that on the box! (c) Ross Geller

Comment: @konart, a way to deal with this is to properly approach the Go documentation: it's terse and as dry as possible, so you do not *skim through* it—as one usually does with other bits of documentation, in our time of clip thinking,—but actually read it top to bottom. This really works, trust me ;-)